How to reuse the result of the Table-Valued User-Defined Function call?
The result of a table-valued user-defined SQL function (tab-ufn) can be used as a table in other SQL commands.
Say, I have several SELECT commands combined by UNION where each of the SELECT uses a JOIN with the result of the tab-ufn with the same arguments. (This way, the tab-ufn returns always the same result.) Something like this:
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table1 JOIN dbo.ufn_tab(x, y) ON <condition1>
 WHERE <condition2>
UNION
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table2 JOIN dbo.ufn_tab(x, y) ON <condition3>
 WHERE <condition4>
UNION
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table3 JOIN dbo.ufn_tab(x, y) ON <condition5>
 WHERE <condition6>
UNION
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table4 JOIN dbo.ufn_tab(x, y) ON <condition7>
 WHERE <condition8>

How can I avoid repeated call to the same tab-ufn? Is there any way that allows capture (without copying) the resulting row-set to be used as the table? (I mean in other SQL code, on the SQL server.) I would like to avoid INSERTing the result to a temporary table. Is that possible?
I am using MS-SQL (several of them, not very old versions).

do the union of tables only and include x,y and then make one call to ufn_tab

@siggemannen It doesn't seem immediately obvious that this will give the same result. It would be if it was union all.

@GSerg true, one might need another distinct on the outside :/ But i suspect UNION here is a mistake and it should've been UNION ALL

Yes, I am actually using UNION ALL. The above was just for illustration of the multiple call of the function. The DISTINCT or not is similar -- this is what I know how to do. Simply ignore those "details". I would like to learn how to solve the "core" of the problem.

Each of the JOINs with the ufn_tab() highly reduces the number of rows of the SELECT. Would the UNION tables first and then JOIN with ufn_tab() be processed with similar number of processed rows?

You can try it out. But it might be that you are smoked and have to keep copypasting.

You can union the tables first, then join on the result.
SELECT DISTINCT
  a, b, c
FROM (
    SELECT t1.SomeColumn
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE <condition2>

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.SomeColumn
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE <condition4>

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t3.SomeColumn
    FROM table3 t3
    WHERE <condition6>

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t4.SomeColumn
    FROM table4 t4
    WHERE <condition8>
) t
JOIN dbo.ufn_tab(x, y) ON <condition7>

UNION implies DISTINCT, whereas UNION ALL does not, so you would need DISTINCT on the outside. If that is not necessary, as I would imagine, then remove it.

Thanks, I understand that. The JOIN of a single with the ufn_tab highly reduces the number of rows to be then UNIONed. When the tableX are otherwise quite big, is the SQL engine good enough to optimize the things (to create the execution plan and to use the statistics, ...) so that similarly small number of rows is accessed/processed?

Yes it often can, but not always. Please share your execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Actually, we are 3rd party to work with customers Azure SQL, and we have no access to the tools that show the execution plan. Anyway, thanks for the help. I will test the result the old way, by measuring time of execution.
